# Combining 2 observables in RxJava in a given manner

Tags: rx-java

I want to combine 2 observables that emit in the following manner, and I want the result as stated below:

```
                  Timeline ->

Observable 1:     A    B    C
Observable 2:                 1

Desired result: A1 B1 C1
```

CombineLatest gives me just C1, and Zip would provide just A1. Not sure which operator should I be using.

Comment: Is `Observable2` a `Single` rather than `Observable`?

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like that -

```swift
        final Observable<String> letters = ...
        final Observable<Integer> numbers = ...

        final ConnectableObservable<Integer> sharedNumbers = numbers.publish();
        final Observable<List<String>> bufferedLetters = letters.buffer(sharedNumbers);
        final Observable<Pair<Integer, List<String>>> buffers = Observable.combineLatest(sharedNumbers, bufferedLetters, new Func2<Integer, List<String>, Pair<Integer, List<String>>>() {
            @Override
            public Pair<Integer, List<String>> call(Integer number, List<String> letters) {
                return new Pair<>(number, letters);
            }
        });
        final Observable<Pair<Integer, String>> pairs = buffers.flatMap(new Func1<Pair<Integer, List<String>>, Observable<Pair<Integer, String>>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Pair<Integer, String>> call(final Pair<Integer, List<String>> buffer) {
                return Observable.from(buffer.second).map(new Func1<String, Pair<Integer, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Pair<Integer, String> call(String letter) {
                        return new Pair<>(buffer.first, letter);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        sharedNumbers.connect();
```

Comment: I guess you didn't take a look at the timeline. I just gave an example. The actual emission from the observables are objects from the network, so I can't really keep a list of strings.

Comment: @Prateek How else can you combine older events with a more recent event? By "letters" I mean "Observable 1" and by "numbers" "Observable 2", not the actual object types. Anyway, see for yourself how the operator works - http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#buffer-rx.Observable-

Answer (score 0):

You need to buffer all items that Observable1 emitted and combined it with every Observable2 item. Here is my code:

```
BehaviorSubject<String> s1 = BehaviorSubject.create();
BehaviorSubject<String> s2 = BehaviorSubject.create();
Observable.combineLatest(s1.scan(new ArrayList<>(), (l, s) -> {
  l.add(s);
  return l;
}), s2, (list, s) -> Observable.fromIterable(list).map(a -> a + s))
    .concatMap(o -> o)
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
s1.onNext("a");
s1.onNext("b");
s1.onNext("c");
s2.onNext("1");
```

and output:

```
a1
b1
c1
```